# Maximum size of walled city in Halacha

Tags: halacha, geography, shiurim-measurements, home-house, arachin-tractate

According to Halacha, is there a maximum size for a walled city as for the mitzvah of Leviticus 25:29-30, redeeming properties you sold within a walled city in a year time period (note this is a hypothetical question, as it is not applicable outside Israel and when the jubilee year doesn’t apply). Is there a maximum amount of population size or miles which would make it lose its status as a walled “city” in halacha?

Comment: I appreciate it, @Kirk but I don't have time this week to wade through the online version of the work and post the link

Comment: @יהושעק are you basing the walk on Yonah? I thought it was a 3 day walk? Also, does a 3 day walk mean that it was a straight walk across or that it would take 3 days to get all around town and effectively communicate the message to the inhabitants? If the latter, then the size being contemplated is significantly reduced (and arguably the archaeological record accords better with the latter).

Comment: @Deuteronomy I believe it's a machlokes. For some reason a contradiction in the Pessukim comes to mind (though I'm not sure if there is, this is all ba'al Peh). IIRC, I've passuk says 3 days, another says that yonah walked for one day. One explanation of this s'tira is that yona (still) didn't want to fully commit to his nevua and only did the bare minimum by walking only a third of the way across the city, the other is that the city was 3 day walk in circumference, but 1 day walk across (i.e., divided by pi).

Comment: @Loani thanks, very interesting